# ModSecurity: What do MULTIPART_DATA_BEFORE and MULTIPART_DATA_AFTER mean?

Tags: mod-security

I'm getting the following ModSecurity error when posting form data to a LiquidWeb server:

```
Multipart request body failed strict validation: PE 0, BQ 0, BW 0, DB 1, DA 1, HF 0, LF 0, SM 0, IQ 0, IP 0, IH 0, FL 0
```

As you can see DB and DA have been set to 1. And looking at the [ModSecurity docs](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual#wiki-MULTIPART_STRICT_ERROR) on this, DB means MULTIPART_DATA_BEFORE and DA means MULTIPART_DATA_AFTER, which isn't very helpful.

Can anyone explain what these mean?

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not cent percent sure about their actual definitions.
DB and DA should correspond to preamble and epilogue around [multi-part boundaries](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046) . Which may sound platonic at first, until you read about the recent [BadEpilogue Malware evasion](http://www.certego.net/en/news/badepilogue-the-perfect-evasion/).

After-all, organizations which has this detection turned-on are not completely paranoiac.